# ImageResizer using AzureReader2 returns 404s for resized images when deployed in RELEASE mode to Azure website

Tags: azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, imageresizer

I have an MVC website (MVC 5.2.2.0), that uses [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) and Azure Blob Storage, using the [AzureReader2 plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/azurereader2).

I am using default settings, so images will be accessed through /azure/images (where "images" is the name of my container), and it works perfectly in development - and if I deploy to an Azure Website using ***Debug*** settings.

If I deploy using ***Release*** settings, images stop working and return 404s with a times new roman text "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.", as shown below.

[image]

This is from my web.config, and is NOT modified on release (I double-checked):

```
<resizer>
 <plugins>
  <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
  <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=[accountname];AccountKey=[KEY]" endpoint="http://[account].blob.core.windows.net/" />
  <add name="DiskCache" />
 </plugins>
</resizer>
```

I am lost and don't know where to begin troubleshooting. I have tried disabling DiskCache plugin, which does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because your configuration is enabling **pre-compilation** when you switch to release mode. Disabling pre-compilation should allow VirtualPathProviders to work again.

See ["File Not Found - cause #4" in the Troubleshooting Guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/troubleshoot#file-not-found) for more information.